# mongodb c++ query for a day range

Tags: c++, mongodb, isodate

I have a structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("562dcec2430a5684fedce1b0"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-10-26T06:57:06.619Z"),
    "query" : "google com"
}
```

how can I filter queries those dates are 2015-10-25?
or If I would like to filter queries those are asked by a day ago, is there a c++ expression like this:

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor =
  mongo_conn->query("database1.collection1",
                    BSON("date" <<
                      BSON("$gte" << BSON(datenow - "1 day")
                      << "$lt" << BSON(datenow))));
```

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
mongo::BSONObj date_range =     
BSON("date" << mongo::BSONObjBuilder().appendDate("lte", GetTimeInMs())
 .appendDate("gte", GetTimeInMs() - 1000*60*60*24).obj());
```

although appendDate will return object in this way: "2015-10-28T13:52:56.218+0800", but it still comparable with IOSDate